# Process still running C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I've looked around on how to solve this problem but I must be looking for the wrong thing because I can't find anything.

I've just started learning C++ and I've come across a problem where once it has been compiled and is running, It'll finish or i'll close the window, yet the process is still running. When I then use task manager to end the process it does absolutely noting.

Here is something I wrote up, what is it that I need to add in or take out to make sure that the process is terminated once it has finished or is manually closed?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int grade;

    cout << "Please enter your grade (0-100) ";
    cin >> grade;

    if (grade == 100)
        cout << "You got a perfect score" << endl;
    else if (grade >= 90 && grade <= 99)
        cout << "You scored an A" << endl;
    else if (grade >= 80 && grade < 90)
        cout << "You scored a B" << endl;
    else if (grade >= 70 && grade < 80)
        cout << "You scored a C" << endl;
    else if (grade >= 60 && grade < 70)
        cout << "You scored a D" << endl;
    else if (grade >= 0 && grade < 60)
        cout << "You scored an F" << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Generally speaking, your `main` is not returning anything.  Try `return 0;` on the last line following the `pause`.  I have not tried having a main with no return when it should be present.

Comment: Which compiler is being used?

Comment: Adding return 0; worked perfectly. I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 's C++ compiler

Comment: When you are running it, is this inside the debugger or double clicking the executable, both?

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that system("pause"); is preventing the code from exiting.  By calling that, you're telling the program to wait for some kind of input before exiting.

In addition, you need to have a return value at the end of the function, as the OS is expecting an int value to be returned.

[See this for alternatives](http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-61.html)

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are using a

> system("pause");

and your code waits for an input,

And do care about your main function return type!